# swift dictionary nested array manipulation - cannot mutate nested array inside dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift

```
var dict = ["alpha": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]
// output : ["alpha": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]

var alphaList = dict["alpha"]
// output : {["a", "b", "c", "d"]

alphaList?.removeAtIndex(1)
// output : {Some "b"}

alphaList
// output : {["a", "c", "d"]}

dict
// output : ["alpha": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]
```

Why is 'dict' not altered? Is it because 'alphaList' is a copy of the array and not the actual array inside the dictionary? Can anyone point me where in Swift language documentation I can find this information?

What is the correct/functional way to manipulate values (of complex type) of a dictionary?

Comment: It looks like when getting a reference to an array inside a dictionary it is in fact a copy/different instance -- When playing in a playground i got

`var d = ["t": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]] // ["t": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]`

`var a = d["t"] // {["a", "b", "c", "d"]}`

`a?.removeAtIndex(1) // {Some "b"}`

`a // {["a", "c", "d"]}`

`d // ["t": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]`


`unsafeAddressOf(a!) // "UnsafePointer(0x7FF8C1C088C0)"`

`unsafeAddressOf(d["t"]!) // "UnsafePointer(0x7FF8C1F00990)"`

`unsafeAddressOf(d) // "UnsafePointer(0x7FF8C1C00120)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question yes it creates the copy of the value in your case the value is Array

```
    var alphaList = dict["alpha"] 
/* which is the copy of original array 
changing it will change the local array alphaList as you can see by your output */
    output : {Some "b"}
```

In order to get the original array directly use

```
dict["alpha"]?.removeAtIndex(1)
```

Or update it using the key

```
alphaList?.removeAtIndex(1)
dict["alpha"] = alphaList
```

Apple : [Assignment and Copy Behavior for Strings, Arrays, and Dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_145)

Swift’s String, Array, and Dictionary types are implemented as structures. This means that strings, arrays, and dictionaries are copied when they are assigned to a new constant or variable, or when they are passed to a function or method.

This behavior is different from NSString, NSArray, and NSDictionary in Foundation, which are implemented as classes, not structures. NSString, NSArray, and NSDictionary instances are always assigned and passed around as a reference to an existing instance, rather than as a copy. "

Answer (score 1):

Swift arrays and dictionaries are value (`struct`) times. There are only one reference to such instance. While `NSArray` and `NSDictonary` are `class` type and there could be multiple references to such instances.

The statement `var alphaList = dict["alpha"]` makes copy for `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, so you cannot change the original array.

If you want to mutate original `"alpha"` you have to use `dict` as root variable:

```
dict["alpha"]?.removeAtIndex(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, `alphaList` is a copy, hence any change you make on it is local and does not affect the original array. The documentation describes that in [Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_145).

The only way to make changes to an array after extracting it from somewhere else is by passing the array to a function by reference, using the `inout` parameter modifier:

```
func modifyAlphaList(inout alphaList: [String]?) {
    alphaList?.removeAtIndex(1)
}

modifyAlphaList(&dict["alpha"])
dict // (.0 "alpha", ["a", "c", "d"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This link should help

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_150

Swift’s String, Array, and Dictionary types are implemented as structures. This means that strings, arrays, and dictionaries are copied when they are assigned to a new constant or variable, or when they are passed to a function or method.