# Mutating nested arrays in Swift Dictionary through custom accessor method

Tags: swift, generics

Say that we have a dictionary of arrays:

```
var dict: [Int: [Int]] = [:]
```

Is there something special about Dictionary's subscript methods? Can somebody explain why the following in-place append works:

```
dict[1] = [] 
dict[1]?.append(200)
// dict is now [1: [200]]
```

but the following doesn't:

```
var xs = dict[1]
xs?.append(300)
// dict is still [1: [200]], not [1: [200, 300]]
```

I (kind of) understand why the latter doesn't update the original dictionary, as it creates a copy of the array. But I don't understand why the first one works, I would assume that it similarly creates a copy.

More over (this is the actual problem I have), can I implement a method that allows similar in-place update behavior? The following code doesn't work:

```
extension Dictionary { 
    func mget(key: Key) -> Value? { 
        return self[key]
    } 
}
dict.mget(1)?.append(400)
```

It produces the following error:

```
49> d.mget(1)?.append(400)
repl.swift:49:12: error: immutable value of type '[Int]' only 
                  has mutating members named 'append' 
                  d.mget(1)?.append(400)
                           ^ ~~~~~~
```

Comment: Dictionary is a *value type*, so `var xs = dict[1]` creates an *independent* copy. The same is true for `dict.mget(1)`.

Comment: But why the subscript syntax works so that it doesn't create a copy? Can I achieve similar functionality with my custom methods?

Comment: `dict[1]?.append(200)` modifies `dict`, this is also described in the Swift book in the chapter about optional chaining. `xs?.append(300)` modifies `xs`, which is a copy of `dict[1]`. – Have also a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26397726/1187415 to the linked "duplicate".

Comment: Sorry, but the question doesn't have anything to do with optional chaining. I got a correct answer in the Apple forums, the reason is that subscript operation works like properties and has getter and setter implementations to implement both read and write operations.

Comment: Furthermore, due to subscript being a special case, it isn't possible to implement a similar behavior through getter access methods or custom operators.

Comment: The Swift chapter "Optional Chaining" has a subsection "Accessing Subscripts of Optional Type" which is what I meant. The example `testScores["Bev"]?[0]++` is quite similar to your problem.